# FFMPEG: H265, -Preset Options Are Out Of Order

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression

With H264, the higher the preset (ex., -preset 9), the slower yet better the compression (the wait is long long but the file size is small). However, with H265, I found that -preset 2 gets the best compression! -preset 1 and 0 are increasingly faster but weaker at compressing. Meanwhile, -preset 3 to 9 are increasingly slower yet result in worse compression (no reward for the longer wait)! I've tested this many times on many different video files. Is this a bug?

Comment: The reward is better quality. Check the PSNR/SSIM scores.

Comment: Ah, I thought the -preset command only affected thoroughness of compression and had no affect on quality. It looks like I was wrong in thinking that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The reward is better quality. Check the PSNR/SSIM scores."
– Gyan